# Fill text box on basis of Selected text of another auto completed text box c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

[screenshot of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfcgG.jpg)

i have two text boxes **txtPartNumber**, **txtDesc**. Part Number text box is autocomplete using below code on text_change_event which works fine.

```
            try
            {
                string query = "select [itmPartNumber],[itemDescr] from [vstItems]";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                AutoCompleteStringCollection autoPart = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    autoPart.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
                }
                txtPartNum.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                txtPartNum.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                txtPartNum.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoPart;
            }
```

what im looking for is on **textPartNumber**_leave event  **txtDescr** text box should be filled with description which i get from the database in above query.

screenshot of my form attached above. How do i get that?

Comment: you mean on "lost focus" event. You didn't specify which GUI framework you are using but in any case there should be a similar event.

Comment: C# Windows forms

Comment: You can either use Leave or LostFocus events of textbox. And don't forget to dispose that SqlCommand if you haven't done already.

Comment: i am looking for the code of leave event, any suggestions ? btw i am closing command in `finally { }` block which i haven't pasted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from [Bizhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366064/bizhan) is a fine clue to the answer. Use the Leave event on txtPartNumber to update txtDesc with Description.
Some suggestions to improve your solution:

Query the database and build the **AutoCompleteStringCollection** OUT of the **TextChanged** event of txtPartNumber. **TextChanged** is raised on every keystroke of the user. It will be called many times before the whole code gets entered in the textbox control. (In general, avoid doing so many things in event handlers, use private methods instead.)

While you are reading *itmPartNumber*, read *itemDescr* as well. You could use a **Dictionary** to store both and later retrive the description, when the user had decided wich part to enter.